# How can I change similarly named inner classes using a loop?

Tags: c#, class, inner-classes, ranorex

This problem is specific to Ranorex Android mobile dev which limits how I can set up my classes, but a generic C# solution would also help me.

I have been trying to find a way to switch through inner classes that only vary slightly. If there is a way to include a variable into class names that would be great, but I have had trouble finding any sources for it. Currently I have 8 different variations hard coded in an if statement (I can change it to a switch but that's not the solution I want) that is essentially as following.

```
if (device_name == d1_name)
{
    device_stats.Add("Device Name", d1_name);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(device_stats["Device Name"]);
    device_stats.Add("Status", repo.Android.Settings.d1.deviceStatus.TextValue);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Status:\t" + device_stats["Status"]);

    repo.Android.Settings.d1.screen.Touch();
}
else if(device_name == d2_name)
{
    device_stats.Add("Device Name", d2_name);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(device_stats["Device Name"]);
    device_stats.Add("Status", repo.Android.Settings.d2.deviceStatus.TextValue);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Status:\t" + device_stats["Status"]);

    repo.Android.Settings.d2.screen.Touch();
}
else if (device_name == d3_name)
{
    device_stats.Add("Device Name", d3_name);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(device_stats["Device Name"]);
    device_stats.Add("Status", repo.Android.Settings.d3.deviceStatus.TextValue);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Status:\t" + device_stats["Status"]);

    repo.Android.Settings.d3.screen.Touch();
}
```

As you can see, the only difference between the cases are the device name. I have been trying to find a way that I can loop through the small portion of code and replace the d'#' with the iterator. Something like this.

```
for (i_device = 0; i_device < n_device; i_device++)
{
    string i_str = int2str(i_device);
    if(device_name == device_name_arr[i_device])
    {
        device_stats.Add("Device Name", device_name_arr[i_device]));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(device_stats["Device Name"]);
        device_stats.Add("Status", repo.Android.Settings.StringToInnerClass("d" + i_str).deviceStatus.TextValue);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Status:\t" + device_stats["Status"]);

        repo.Android.Settings.StringToInnerClass("d" + i_str).screen.Touch();
    }
}
```

I don't think there is a way to include a function in a class call, so I'm wondering if i just store the classes somehow in an array already? I am not sure there is a way to do this without some coding magic.

### Update

I started building something that is way beyond me and I'm not even sure this is the right route for now. I think I'm fine with hard coding this portion rather than coming up with a crazy solution. This is where I was going if you are interested. (Some of the classes are auto generated and a little weird). It doesn't even compile

```
List<TestRepositoryFolders> device_folder = new List<TestRepositoryFolders>();
device_folder.Add(D5Folder.repo.Android.Settings.d5);
device_folder.Add(D6Folder.repo.Android.Settings.d6);

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("please" + (TestRepositoryFolders)device_folder[0].deviceName.TextValue);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("please" + (TestRepositoryFolders)device_folder[1].deviceName.TextValue);
```

Comment: What about making a base class the the other classes inherit?

Comment: Change `device_name_arr` to an array of pairs of device name and a delegate that gets `d1`, `d2`, etc. for the device with that name. Use the function to get that device setting and then use `.deviceStatus.TextValue` from that.

Comment: I believe a base class wouldn't help me break down the code into a loop?

Comment: What are the types of `repo.Android.Settings` and the `d1` etc. properties it has?

Comment: sorry I was trying to understand your answer. You want me to make an array that would be `[repo.Android.Settings.d1, repo.Android.Settings.d2, ...]; ` and to use it i could do `arr[i].deviceStatus.TstValue;`?

Comment: That might work but that wasn't what I was suggesting. I can give you more detail in an answer if you can tell me what those types are.

Comment: I will try to do that quick then and see if it works. Thank you!

Comment: Just keep in mind that the way you interpreted it requires that those instances don't change because you'd be creating a copy of the instance in that array. If new instances can be assigned you need something that can account for that.

Comment: Would be nice if you could do something like `repo.Android.Settings[device_name].deviceStatus.TextValue`

Comment: agreed :( I was also trying to find a `string2class` function or anything like that

Comment: @Danielme - I made an assumption about one of the type names (and took the other from your edit) so I could post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* write the `StringToInnerClass` you had in your code as an extension method that uses reflection to get the device-specific settings object you want, although that would be overkill in this case.

The loop was a good idea.  You can expand the array of device names to an array of name/function pairs to accomplish your goal, assuming that `d1`, `d2`, etc. are of the same type.

Start by constructing metadata for the devices: that consists of the device name and a settings retrieval function.  I've used tuples here to avoid defining a type for now but you should consider doing that eventually.

*Since you didn't answer my question about type names, this assumes that `repo.Android.Settings` is of type `AndroidSettings`.  `d1` etc. appear to be of type `TestRepositoryFolders` according to your edit.  Change these to the actual types as needed to get it to work.*

```cs
List<(string Name, Func<AndroidSettings, TestRepositoryFolders> GetDeviceSettings)> device_meta =
    new List<(string, Func<AndroidSettings, TestRepositoryFolders>)>()
{
    (d1_name, s => s.d1),
    (d2_name, s => s.d2),
    (d3_name, s => s.d3)
};
```

Then change your loop to use the `Name` property to test the device name and the `GetDeviceSettings` property to get the settings for that device.  You can break out of the loop once you get a match.

```cs
for (int i_device = 0; i_device < device_meta.Count; i_device++)
{
    if (device_name == device_meta[i_device].Name)
    {
        device_stats.Add("Device Name", device_meta[i_device].Name));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(device_stats["Device Name"]);

        var deviceSettings = device_meta[i_device].GetDeviceSettings();

        device_stats.Add("Status", deviceSettings.deviceStatus.TextValue);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Status:\t" + device_stats["Status"]);

        deviceSettings.screen.Touch();

        break;
    }
}
```

You may encounter other places where you need to loop through devices and do some other operation.  That would be the time (if not sooner) to convert the tuples to a type of your own making and include the new metadata needed to perform that operation.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want to do is what we call type reflection.

```
var device = typeof(repo.Android.Settings).GetField("d" + i, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null) as TestRepositoryFolders
```

This method is bit harder to read but once in place requires no changing whenever a new device is added.